# withCount() - get difference of 2 counts

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have a table that has a column `is_up_vote` = `true|false`

I am trying to write a query using `withCount()` so it returns me the sum of true values and false values.

`select COUNT(is_up_vote) from comment_votes WHERE is_up_vote = true` returns 17

`select COUNT(is_up_vote) from comment_votes WHERE is_up_vote = false` returns 15

However I couldn't figure out how to get different of them, so the total returns 2.

What I tried is:

```
Model::withCount(['votes' => function($q) {
 $q->selectRaw(
    '(SUM (COUNT(is_up_vote) WHERE is_up_vote = true) - (COUNT(is_up_vote) WHERE is_up_vote = false) )'
 );
}]);
```

But this returns 17+15 = 32

without `SUM()`, it's also returning 32.

```
$q->selectRaw(
   '( (COUNT(is_up_vote) WHERE is_up_vote = true) - (COUNT(is_up_vote) WHERE is_up_vote = false) )'
);
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:

If I try one side, it ignores the where and still returns 32, so the where is not getting called (where it does in sql)

```
return $query->withCount(['votes' => function($q) {
   $q->selectRaw('(COUNT(is_up_vote) WHERE is_up_vote = true)');
}]);
```

maunal sequel query returns 17:

```
select COUNT(is_up_vote) from comment_votes WHERE is_up_vote = true
```

---

**Edit 2:**

```
$query->withCount([
    'votes as up_votes_count' => function($q) {
        $q->where('is_up_vote', true);
    },
    'votes as down_votes_count' => function($q) {
        $q->where('is_up_vote', false);
    },
]);
```

The only thing that I could make work is this, but it'd need extra step for getting the total, so I didn't really like this approach. I'm sure someone more proficient with queries can come up with something with direct query.

Comment: Remove the `SUM()`

Comment: @JeremyHarris Still returns same

Answer (score 0):

withCount may not be able to handle this case. what about using [addSelect](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#advanced-subqueries) to calculate the votes count.

```
return Model::addSelect(['votes_count' => Vote::selectRaw('( (COUNT(is_up_vote) WHERE is_up_vote = true) - (COUNT(is_up_vote) WHERE is_up_vote = false) )')
    ->whereColumn('parent_id', 'parents.id')
])->get();
```

I don't know whether the sub-query is gonna work. But you know the idea.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting approach but I couldn't use an `.. => EloquentModel::selectRaw()` syntax, it throws _"stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"_

Answer (score 0):

```
create table comment_votes
(
    is_up_vote tinyint(1) default 1 null
);
```

```
insert into comment_votes values (true),(true),(true),(true),(true),(true),(true),(true),(true),(true),(true),(true),(true),(true),(true),(true),(true);
insert into comment_votes values (false),(false),(false),(false),(false),(false),(false),(false),(false),(false),(false),(false),(false),(false),(false);
```

`select COUNT(is_up_vote) from comment_votes WHERE is_up_vote = true;`

returns 17
`select COUNT(is_up_vote) from comment_votes WHERE is_up_vote = false;`

returns 15
`select (abs(2 * sum(is_up_vote) - count(*))) from comment_votes;`

returns 2

Explain:

trueValues + falseValues = total
falseValues = total - trueValues
trueValues - falseValues = x
trueValues - (total - trueValues) = x
2 * trueValues - total = x

trueValues = sum(is_up_vote)  [only trues stored as 1 are counted]
total = count(*)

Abs function is to convert the result to positive in case of negative

Isn't it correct?

Comment: This still returns the total

Answer (score 0):

According to the instructions commented by @Jefferson Pessanha, just using `Model::selectRaw('(abs(2 * sum(is_up_vote) - count(*)))')->get();` would be enough

Comment: Well, it's a relationship, how can you add selectRaw to subquery format?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
select 
sum( if(is_up_vote= true, 1, 0) ) as uptrue, 
sum( if(is_up_vote= false, 1, 0) ) as upfalse,
sum( if(is_up_vote= true, 1, -1) ) as updiff
from comment_votes
```

**Edit: 1**

Instead of checking if it is true or false, try this.

```
select 
sum( if(is_up_vote, 1, 0) ) as uptrue, 
sum( if(is_up_vote, 0, 1) ) as upfalse,
sum( if(is_up_vote, 1, -1) ) as updiff
from comment_votes
```

Comment: It's still 32. It seem to not care about "where" part unless I write it as `$q->where(''is_up_vote", true)`

Comment: Try as mentioned above in my Edit 1:

Comment: Tried? Any feedback?